# Is there a list of all my posts, including deleted?

Tags: support, answers, deleted-answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Show all of my question/answers to me even if they are deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted)

I deleted several posts of mine that only had 1-3 votes because I was under the impression that I wouldn't lose rep. points. But then, of course, a recalculation occurred and I lost a lot of points. I know that if I go to a post I deleted, I can un-delete it. But I don't remember all of the questions that had answers I deleted.

Is there any list that includes my deleted posts, or all posts including deleted ones? I looked in my activity log and deleted ones aren't included. Is there a StackExchange public query, that would show this information?

Comment: FYI, it's generally considered bad form to delete your questions unless they were seriously flawed. Please leave them around so others can benefit from them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think so.  Since there were only a handful of them, I went through and undeleted all your positively voted answers that were "deleted by owner."  Please be careful when deleting content folks!  :)