# Is there a way to see my deleted answers?

Tags: support, deleted-answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a list of all my posts, including deleted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93659/is-there-a-list-of-all-my-posts-including-deleted)

I deleted an answer a few weeks ago, and now I'd really like to see it.  Lesson learned about deleting content, but is there any way to get a list of all of my old deleted answers?

And no, my Stack Overflow addiction has rendered my browser's history—both at work and at home—useless.

The last time I looked through the old questions on this topic here on Meta, I *thought* I saw something about 10K users seeing all their deleted answers appended to the end of their question list when they view their profile, but I can say now that doesn't seem to be the case (  :-D  )

Is there **any** way to just get a dump of all the question ids for which I have a deleted answer?  A simple script could generate links therefrom.

Comment: Can you remember the question? You should be able to see your deleted answers when you view the question.

Comment: @Chris -  I know.  And no.  I wish I did.

Comment: I suppose you could bother a community moderator via an attention flag on an unrelated post of yours. More work for them, but there really isn't any other way.

Comment: You've deleted quite a lot of answers in the last few weeks.

Comment: @mmyers - yeah, I had a lot of mediocre, zero-vote cruft from my younger years (and maybe one or two half-baked answers from answering too quickly).  Can you (easily) get a dump of the question ids?

Comment: @GhostofChristmasPresents - so is a csv of question ids on which I've ever deleted an answer not possible?  That's fine if not, was just wanting to put this to bed.

Comment: You have 701 answers, included deleted ones. While a moderator could in theory go through the list and copy out the deleted ones, that's pretty unlikely to happen. Now on the other hand, if you knew exactly what was in the post you're looking for, I could make use of the deleted:1 search operator to hunt it down.

Comment: @GhostofChristmasPresents (I just caught that pun—nice) - I wouldn't expect a mod to sift through about 250 deleted answers.  I was hoping there would be a way to run a query and export the results to a csv in about 10 minutes.  If that's not the case, then I guess I have my answer.  Thank you for answering :)

Comment: Well, sure, a dev could do that. But going from Jeff's answer on the duplicate's duplicate, he's not real big on the idea of making it visible.

Comment: @GhostofChristmasPresents - fair enough.  It's not important enough to bother a dev.  Not sure why I thought a mod could run such a query.  Ok, in any event, thanks for your time.