# Can I see my answer to someone else's deleted post?

Tags: support, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

Can I somehow see the answer I gave to a deleted question from someone else?

I know this *seems* like a duplicate of [Show all of my question/answers to me even if they are deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted) or [Is there a way to see my deleted answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115010/is-there-a-way-to-see-my-deleted-answers), but it is slightly different and not quite covered as far as I can see. It is not *my* question or *my* answer that was deleted; instead the original question (posted by another user) was deleted, dragging my answer with it into the trash bin.

The reason I'd like to see my answer ([this is the original link](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/23798/what-will-i-miss-from-windows/23956#23956)) is that I put quite some time in wording and finetuning it, and I am interested in using it for something else, even though it might not fit on stackexchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go (this is the full text dump). I used this trick [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99593/how-is-the-editing-of-deleted-posts-supposed-to-behave/180751#180751):

```
After switching to Mac about 3 years ago (partly, still using Windows 7 at work), things I still miss in OSX :

* I generally find **Window management** better in Windows:

  * you can't resize on all sides — (although is natively possible since  OS X Lion)
  * there's no build-in Aero Snap-like feature (I am using [Cinch](http://irradiatedsoftware.com/cinch/) and [SizeUp](http://irradiatedsoftware.com/sizeup/) as replacement)
  * the result of clicking the green zoom/maximize button is not very consistent across applications (this is acknowledged by many Apple users, see e.g [here](http://gigaom.com/apple/hey-apple-fix-the-green-button-already/)) . I stopped using it, in favor of just manual resizing or the two earlier mentioned tools.

* **No good overall keyboard shortcut support** (although some people claim differently). On Windows you can literally do everything without using a mouse, I have yet to find something that isn't accessible via the keyboard. For example, the right-click menu in Windows is (almost) system-wide available via <kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>F10</kbd>; each window has a context menu that is accessible via <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>space</kbd>, ... <br>On Mac, shortcut assignment miss consistency and is not complete (see e.g this answer to a shortcut question: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/10858/what-is-the-button-in-the-upper-right-of-windows/10859#10859). You can define custom shortcuts, but it's kind of awkward and you can't use them on other systems you occasionally use.

* **Native Microsoft Office**. Although I found Office 2011 for Mac a big improvement over the previous versions, but it is still not the experience like on Windows. <br>(On a sidenote, and related to my previous point, I was happy to notice the Office for Mac team went through the trouble of implementing shift-F10 in Office Word, you'll notice that the pop-up menu doesn't look native)

* **Folder browsing using the Finder**. Although finder has three or four different layouts, none of them really fits me. I especially miss the folder tree; and some small things like double-clicking a folder divider to make it auto-size.<br> There are some alternatives like [PathFinder](http://www.cocoatech.com/) (not free) etc, but after trying them for some them I dropped them because it still does not completely feel right.

* If you're not into **iTunes** for managing your music, there really isn't a good alternative on OSX. I dislike iTunes because it doesn't really play 100% well with putting music on a shared network drive (NAS), it does not really has a playlist view (you have iTunes DJ view but it is sort of different). You might want to look at e.g. [this roundup of alternatives](http://www.unplggd.com/unplggd/software/10-mac-osx-music-player-alternatives-to-itunes-roundup-139519). I've considered [aTunes](http://www.atunes.org) (use it on windows) and [Amarok](http://amarok.kde.org/) (use it on Ubuntu) before, but I did switch back to iTunes eventually.

* the **OSX 'religion'** you have to deal with, i.e. Microsoft/Windows online community support feels less biased and has less the tendency of 'let-me-convince-you' (see e.g. the multiple no-virus comments in another answer).

* **No *date-deleted* column in Trash**. So, if you don't regularly clean your trash, it is almost impossible to find recently (e.g. accidental) deleted files.

Things that are awkward first, but were no problem for me after a while:

*  Applications remain open after closing the last window. I even started to like it, because these applications launch faster
* using <kbd>cmd</kbd> instead of <kbd>ctrl</kbd>. Just a matter of getting used to
* Installing applications by drag and drop. The first application I installed was Firefox, and I couldn't for the life of me figure out what the image (depicting the firefox logo pointing with an arrow to an A-icon) was trying to say me, or how to install it. Had to call a friend to ask what to do :-)<br>Also, sometimes application downloads come onion-like with several layers to unpack before getting to the application itself (e.g. you download a zip or tar file, which contains a dmg, which contains the actual application)
* <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>tab</kbd> switching through windows. The problem is that this shortcut only cycles through *applications*, not windows. After fighting this for some months, the solution for me was using [Exposé](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expos%C3%A9_(Mac_OS_X)) instead.


On the other side, native things from OSX I've come to miss greatly on Windows 7:

* Exposé
* quick system updates
* no worries about viruses
* drag-and-drop installation (after you get used to it)
* using spotlight to do quick calculations
* much less general annoying software update popups (Java, Adobe Acrobat, this, that, ...)
* Time-machine, which really is a painless and worry free backup solution.
* OSX has much less tendency to build up cruft and slow down over time. Whereas I re-installed a fresh copy of Windows every year or so, my first fresh re-install was after 2.5 years when I upgraded to Snow Leopard
* the fact that you can rename files when they are in use
* [not really OSX, but the reason I bought an iMac] the very compact and almost cable-less design of the iMac
* completely subjective: it looks better

If my iMac breaks down, would I buy a new one, or switch back to Windows? I haven't made my mind up on that one. Hopefully by then Ubuntu will have matured enough, so I might go with that one.
```

Comment: Neat trick ! A shame we need a trick for this, though.

Comment: @Rabarberski: Currently, it is status-bydesign (hopefully it stays that way). Otherwise, we have to rely on 10k rep (or equivalent on beta sites) people on that site to retrieve the content.